# Master Detail in iPad Storyboard

Tags: ios

I am facing a problem in master detail i know that masterDetail need to be the Initial ViewController in the storyboard and i wanted to make a MENU when button is pressed i load the `MasterDetail`...
what i have Tried till now :

I put the `MENU ViewController` in storyBoard called for example `MENU.storyboard`
the `MasterDetail viewController` in another StoryBoard called `MainStory.storyboard`
then from the build phases i choose the main entry for storyBoard is `MENU`
Finally in `MENU` Class (ex `MenuClass.m`) add action for button when pressed

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStory" bundle:nil];
MyNewViewController *myVC = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"myViewCont"];
```

and then add this view.

The Problem is : when i do this steps in iphone StoryBoard it works perfectly.
BUT when i do same simple steps in iPad StoryBoard the code crash (before even Displayin the MENU storyBoard)...
 and when i Comment the code in

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions     ->appDelegate
```

the Menu StoryBoard appear but when button is pressed to load MasterDetail I got a crash
ofcourse because I commented the MasterDetail initialization Code in the appDelegate.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be easier to use only 1 storyboard and set your menu `ViewController` as the `rootViewController` of the app. And then link the menu `ViewController` to the `NavigationController` leading to the Master Detail views with a modal segue.

[image]

Comment: i done exactly like what u say it crash with the same error "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIViewController topViewController]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8131380'"

Comment: Try It in iPad StoryBoard not iPhone StoryBoard

Comment: Just saw the `SplitViewController` and I checked the documentation and it says: `"you must always install the view from a UISplitViewController object as the root view of your application’s window. [...] Split view controllers cannot be presented modally."`. So 2 storyboard seems to be the only way to do it then but I don't know how to do it sorry.